# pandas spearman correlation weird?

Tags: pandas, correlation

Is it possible to have this two correlations different?

Pandas version 0.18.1

```
from pandas import Series
a = ['Arsenal', 'Leicester', 'Man City', 'Tottenham', 'Crystal Palace']
b = ['Arsenal', 'Leicester', 'Man City', 'Tottenham', 'Man United']
c = ['Arsenal', 'Leicester', 'Man City', 'Tottenham', 'Man United']
d = ['Arsenal', 'Leicester', 'Man City', 'Tottenham', 'West Ham']


Series(a).corr(Series(b), method="spearman")
0.69999999999999996
Series(c).corr(Series(d), method="spearman")
0.8999999999999998
```

Comment: python 3.5.2 and anaconda 4.4.1

Comment: pandas has to rank these strings somehow and so they are ranked alphabetically. Teams may therefore be ranked differently depending on what other teams are present. So pandas is calculating "correctly", but this just isn't the operation you wanted.

Comment: I'm no statistician but isn't correlation needed to be done on two series of numbers? What where you expecting as output? In Pandas 0.19.2 the sample code above crashes because strings aren't floats.

Comment: For Spearman's correlation you need to have data that is measured on ordinal scale. What you have is nominal. I suggest you take a look at similarity measures for nominal attributes instead of calculating correlations.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior.  [Spearman Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient) is a *rank* correlation, meaning it is performed on the rankings of your data, not the data itself.  In your example, the data itself may only vary in one location, but the differences in the data produces different rankings.  As suggested in the comments, Spearman correlation probably isn't what you actually want to use.

To expand further, underneath the hood pandas is essentially calling [`scipy.stats.spearmanr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html) to compute the correlation.  Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3206-L3345) for `spearmanr`, it essentially ends up using [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) to perform the ranking, then [`np.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) to get the correlation:

```
corr1 = np.corrcoef(ss.rankdata(a), ss.rankdata(b))[1,0]
corr2 = np.corrcoef(ss.rankdata(c), ss.rankdata(d))[1,0]
```

Which produces the same values you're observing.  Now, look at the rankings used in each correlation calculation:

```
ss.rankdata(a)
[ 1.  3.  4.  5.  2.]

ss.rankdata(b)
[ 1.  2.  3.  5.  4.]

ss.rankdata(c) 
[ 1.  2.  3.  5.  4.]

ss.rankdata(d)
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
```

Notice that the rankings for `a` and `b` differ in three locations, compared to the rankings for `c` and `d` differing in two locations, so we'd expect the resulting correlations to be different.